# Fresh install of Windows 10 Professional. Getting CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED and DRIVER_IRQ_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL errors

Tags: windows, boot

Just reinstalled Windows 10 Pro from MS site with an USB.

Disconnected all other internal HDDs and left the Boot SSD connected. I did a couple of new Windows updates.
(So only software is Windows 10, virus software and Google Chrome)
When it is idle, no problems. As soon as I start doing things I get BSODs with various error codes.

Stop code:CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED

Stop code:DRIVER_IRQ_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL
What failed: storahci.sys

Error dialog box on boot:
WerFault.exe - Application Error
The instruction at 0,00007FFDD502CDDD referenced memory at 0,00007FFDBF31913. The required data was not placed into memory because of an I/O error status of 0xc0000483.

Then cannot repair Windows but can start in safe mode.

See image:

[image]

Intel Core I7 4770K-3.5 GHz QUADCORE
ASUS MBD-Z87,S+L+PCIX16,1150
32GB DDR3 1333MHz RAM (2xCorsair 8GBDIMMS/2xKingston 8GBDIMMS)
Nvidia GeForce GTX960
512GB Sandisk SSD boot drive
4x SATA HDD's
Windows 10 Professional

Comment: Can you clarify this "Disconnected all internal HDDs"... what storage devices were connected/disconnected? You don't state in your spec you had HDD's, just an SSD...so you left the SSD connected?

Comment: Sorry, I am a noob to this.

Comment: The SSD is the boot drive, I have four other SATA drives which are not currently connected. I did that to eliminate issues.

Comment: Thats fine. I'll suggest an edit for you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a RAM issue.

I'd drop down to a single pair of identical chips, and see if the issue goes away. if not, do a RAM check on each pair of sticks, and see if errors are thrown up. If you get errors on all RAM, then you may have a motherboard issue.

The reason I'm thinking this is that you state idle is fine (no RAM changing) but use is crashing the machine.

The only other thing I can think of that would cause this exact behaviour (crash when in use, fine at idle) is an overheating issue. Use something like CPUfan to check the temperatures of the machine, and ensure they aren't getting too hot. (varies per device, but most devices get jumpy above 80Degress  Celcius.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was thinking RAM or SSD from the start.

I will try that a little later and see if it works.

Comment: If there was an issue on the SSD, you'd likely see errors in Event Viewer stating so (if you can get in there).

Comment: Thank you so much Stese, it was the RAM, I have removed the two slower dimms and now it is stable.

Comment: My PC has decided to die again. Same 'Critical_Process_Died' BSOD and then it cannot boot. It can only boot in safe mode. :(

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I'd recommend the same process, checking HDD, RAM and event logs, and see if there is a cause you can find there.